# What language does the XD plugin API support?

Tags: adobe-xd

I saw a pre-launch FAQ on the [Adobe Tech Blog](https://medium.com/adobetech/xd-and-creative-cloud-extensibility-faq-e615dd6ecbfe) that says XD plugins will "be written in modern JavaScript", but what does that mean exactly?

- Can I use ES5?
- What about ES6/ES2015 features?
- Does it support Adobe ExtendScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe XD Extensibility is built on top of a Modern JavaScript engine, which means that it understands both older versions of JavaScript (ES5) and the newer variants (ES6 / ES2015, etc.). ExtendScript is *not* supported for Adobe XD plugins.

Some useful features are listed below:

- ES5

  - Getters / Setters
  - `Array#map`, `Array#foreach`, etc.
- ES6/ES2015+

  - Promises
  - Template literals
  - Classes
  - `const` and `let` (block-scoped variables)
  - Destructuring, default and named parameters
  - Symbols
  - Iterators
  - `async` and `await`

That said, if you're not familiar with ES2015+, you're not required to use it.